# Understanding Flutter didChangeDependencies mechanics

Tags: flutter

After reading the docs [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html) and the `State` lifecycle [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State-class.html), I am still not sure about how `didChangeDependencies` works.

As far as I understand it will be triggered after `initState` and after any change in an `InheritedWidget`, but what are these changes? I think it's important to understand what changes trigger `didChangeDependencies`, so we can understand when and how to use it properly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When Flutter calls [updateShouldNotify()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget/updateShouldNotify.html) and it returns `true`, then widgets that requested an inherited widget in `build()` previously are notified by `didChangeDependencies` being called.

`updateShouldNotify` should return `true` if its state changed since the last time it was called.

Answer (score 8):

### TLDR

As the creator of the Widget, you set it's dependencies (`InheritedWidget`) by using `of` or `maybeOf`, etc., so you should understand when they call [`updateShouldNotify`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget/updateShouldNotify.html) (or they're dependencies call it). It's quite complex:

### Usage

You usually don't have to override this method in `State` because your widget will rebuild when a dependency changes anyway. If you want to do expensive work, like making a network request, then you would avoid making that network request in a normal build, and put this expensive work in `didChangeDependencies` instead. This allows you to only make these expensive operations when a dependency changes. **Tbh**, I struggled to think of a situation where you'd want to make an expensive operation purely if an `InheritedWidget` changes if you're properly structuring your app's logic into services. So I looked at the Flutter framework internals...

### Examples of `didChangeDependencies` overrides:

- Flutter's `Image` widget (the comments are my commentary, and tbh `load` is probably not the right word I'm using, but `resolve` isn't much better IMHO)

```dart
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    _updateInvertColors(); // Checks if the image should inverted or not.
    _resolveImage(); // Reloads the image if necessary?

    if (TickerMode.of(context)) // This method returns a bool: Whether tickers in the given subtree should be enabled or disabled.
      _listenToStream(); // Keep loading the image
    else
      _stopListeningToStream(keepStreamAlive: true); // Be efficient and not read from the stream if not needed. (ticker is false)

    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

- And when is `didChangeDependencies` called? aka. **what are Image's dependencies** (which are all `InheritedWidgets`)? It uses [both `of` and `maybeOf`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/4cc385b4b84ac2f816d939a49ea1f328c4e0b48e/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/image.dart#L52-L55) to register the `InheritedWidget` dependencies, including `MediaQuery`, `Directionality`, `DefaultAssetBundle`, `TickerMode`, `Localizations`. So when these dependencies change/ get updated, `Image`'s `didChangeDependencies` **will be called**.

### What is a dependency?

You make a widget **depend** on a subtype of `InheritedWidget` with `InheritedWidgetType.of(context)`, which internally calls `context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<InheritedWidgetType>();`. So the widget has a dependency on that `InheritedWidget`. For example, `Theme.of(BuildContext context)` can be seen [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/4cc385b4b84ac2f816d939a49ea1f328c4e0b48e/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme.dart#L106-L112).

From the docs inside the Flutter Framework's comments about [`dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/ff5dd54c6e2314e358d2e75d9c2c4fe24ed466d7/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L2150):

> Obtains the nearest **widget** of the given type `T`, which must be the
> type of a concrete [InheritedWidget] subclass, and registers this
> build context with that **widget** such that when that **widget** changes (or
> a new **widget** of that type is introduced, or the **widget** goes away),
> this build context is rebuilt so that it can obtain new values from
> that **widget**.
>
> Once a **widget registers a dependency on a particular type by calling
> this method**, it will be rebuilt, and [State.didChangeDependencies]
> will be called, whenever changes occur relating to that widget until
> the next time the widget or one of its ancestors is moved (for
> example, because an ancestor is added or removed).

There's [more docs, which are really interesting, have a read](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/ff5dd54c6e2314e358d2e75d9c2c4fe24ed466d7/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L2111-L2168).

---

[Jitesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63978520/7365866) is currently just wrong. Dependencies are not Widget's state, they are only relevant for `InheritedWidget`.

Answer (score 6):

`didChangeDependencies()` Called when a dependency of this [State] object changes.
So, exactly **How it gets called?** as by the above definition, it looks like it will be called after state changes but how we come to know the state is changed?
Example:
The below example uses the Provider state management mechanism to update the child widget from the parent widget. The Provider has an attribute called updateShouldNotify which decides whether to state is changed or not. If it's returning true then only didChangeDependencies get called in ChildWidget class.
updateShouldNotify is returning true by default internally, as it knows the state got changed.

**Why do we need updateShouldNotify?**

It’s needed because if someone wants to update the state on a specific condition. Eg: if UI required to show only even values then we can add a condition like

```
updateShouldNotify: (oldValue, newValue) => newValue % 2 == 0,
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ParentWidget({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _ParentWidgetState createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}
class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  int _counter = 0;
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Life Cycle'),
      ),
      body: Provider.value(
        value: _counter,
        updateShouldNotify: (oldValue, newValue) => true,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Press Fab button to increase counter:',
              ),
              ChildWidget()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChildWidgetState createState() => _ChildWidgetState();
}
class _ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  int _counter = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    print('initState(), counter = $_counter');
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    _counter = Provider.of<int>(context);
    print('didChangeDependencies(), counter = $_counter');
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build(), counter = $_counter');
    return Text(
      '$_counter',
    );
  }
}
```

**Output Logs:**

```
I/flutter ( 3779): didChangeDependencies(), counter = 1
I/flutter ( 3779): build(), counter = 1
```

**For more info:**

https://medium.com/@jitsm555/differentiate-between-didchangedependencies-and-initstate-f98a8ae43164

Comment: To me the main source of confusion is the vague notion of a "dependency". I couldn't find a formal definition of what a dependency is in the docs. The only hint is the sentence: _if the previous call to build referenced an InheritedWidget that later changed_. In that regard I find this example confusing: The `build` method of `_ChildWidgetState` does not "reference" any underlying `InheritedWidget`, does it? So how does Flutter even know that the provider is a dependency, if the only "reference" to it comes from `didChangeDependencies` itself?