# How can I reload list again after new record inserted?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I have a listView and it is created using `Future Builder` all the data is fetched from the server and after I added a new record, a record is added successfully into database and `Navigate.pop` to listView page but my list is not refreshed, how can I refresh my list?

```
FutureBuilder<List<NewAddressModel>>(
  future: myAddressList,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    print(snapshot);
    if (snapshot.hasData)
      return addressList(snapshot.data);
    else if (snapshot.hasError)
      return _buildErrorPage(snapshot.error);
    else
      return _buildLoadingPage();
  },
),
```

```
Widget _buildErrorPage(error) => Material(
  child: Center(
    child: Text("ERROR: $error"),
  ),
);
```

```
Widget _buildLoadingPage() => Material(
  child: Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  ),
);
```

```
IconButton (
  icon: Icon(Icons.add_location),
  onPressed: navigateToAddAddress
)

void navigateToAddAddress() async {
  await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
    return AddAddress();
  }));
}
```

Comment: Are you try to use Navigator.push().whenComplete(() { setState() {} })?

Comment: @Abjox can you tell me the same thing for delete if I delete a record, that record is deleted but the list is not refreshed.

Comment: I solved it using @override void didChangeDependencies() { super.didChangeDependencies(); _myList = hitApiGetData(); } is this the correct way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Navigator.push().whenComplete(() { setState() {} }) like this as @Abjox suggested.

```
void navigateToAddAddress() async {
    Navigator.of(context).push
      (new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddAddress()))
        .whenComplete((){setState(() {
//          use here that method by which you load data into listView    
        });});
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Its because when you navigate from one page to another then in the push you should add the whencomplete method as @Abjox said, So that when you navigate back to the Listview page then build method is called and the futurebuilder will fetch the data and show in your data in the list which you inserted in the database.

Comment: can you tell me the same thing for delete if I delete a record, that record is deleted but the list is not refreshed?

Comment: I solved it using   @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _myList = hitApiGetData();
  }  is this the correct way ?

Comment: You should check out his post just for the reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54641746/understanding-flutter-didchangedependencies-mechanics .
If it works then thats great.

Comment: One more help please in this query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59942915/how-can-i-display-image-if-my-list-is-empty

Answer (score 2):

Just reassign `Future` function call to `myAddressList` then call `setState`.

```
Future<void> navigateToAddAddress() async {
  await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => AddAddress(),
    ),
  );
  setState((){
    myAddressList = _fetchAddressListFromServer();
  });
}
```

Comment: hey can you help me in this query                    https://stackoverflow.com/q/59942915/12094392

Comment: @Toyed I added an answer to your [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59942915/12094392). You can try